# Shell Concat string from config file

Tags: shell

I have created config.cfg like this

```
DB_USERNAME='abcdef'
DB_PASSWORD='1234'
```

Then my shell.sh have read config and try to concat string

```
#! /bin/sh
source config.cfg
DB_CONN="${DB_USERNAME}/${DB_PASSWORD}"
echo $DB_CONN
```

expected to be `abcdef/1234` but it returns as `/1234f` which looks like having `/1234` replace on top `abcdef`.

Where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two faults

1. There is no such command as `source` in `/bin/sh`. Perhaps you meant to write `#!/bin/bash` on the first line, or use `. ./config.cfg` instead?
2. The script is failing because you created/edited the file `config.cfg` on a Windows system and copied the file (in binary mode) to your Unix/Linux system.

You can replace the CR/LF line endings with correct LF endings by running `dos2unix config.cfg`, or editing the file in your favourite Unix/Linux-based editor and removing the *^M* characters you'll see at the end of each line.

Comment: you have to use `. ./config.sh` instead of (non existing) `source config.sh`

Comment: @Archemar, true to a point. You only need the leading `./` if config.cfg isn't in the current `PATH`. However, I'll update my Answer to assume it's in the current directory rather than in the `PATH`

Comment: I'll never care to check wether `.` is in `$PATH`, writing `. ./foo` is always faster than `echo $PATH | fgrep .` then `. foo` or `. ./foo`. However, in case of a script, one can test before wether `.` is in `$PATH`.

Comment: Actually I have ./config.cfg should be fine, the faulty part is potentially 2# where i get file from windows. Need to confirm tomorrow